# How do "Photo Booth" and "Measure" (iPad) move the home indicator

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Both the "Photo Booth" and "Measure" apps (in camera mode) on the iPad keep the home indicator at the bottom, doing only subtle changes to the UI elements, and a simple animation on orientation change. Both are camera feeds, so the effect is that the feed is always oriented the same as the camera.

I want to do something similar but I'm not sure how to set up the app (ObjC) without fully changing the orientation, and then rotating the parent view the opposite direction.

My context is a game where we use gravity so that down is always down. This works, the player can infinitely rotate their phone in the vertical plane, but it's incompatible with the normal approach to supportedInterfaceOrientations.

Comment: So is the question really "how do I keep an interface object oriented the same relative to the device while the app rotates"? Or what?

Comment: I already keep the scene in the app oriented constant. Imagine the app was a level, the user can currently infinitely change the rotation of the phone. But I want to move the home indicator.

Comment: When would you move it? I mean, as the phone rotates, there must be some point where you go, NOW! What point would that be?

Comment: I'd like the home indicator to move at the normal times. But everything else on the screen is not rotating because I already use a gravity (acceleration) to keep that level.

Comment: This is probably simple, but I'm missing a piece of the logic.

Comment: Well, the home indicator will move at the normal times if you allow the app as a whole to rotate. And when it does so, as you rightly say, you rotate the main interface the other way, in exact synchronicity with the app rotation, so the _user_ sees the main interface apparently holding still. This is why you are given the rotation animation, so you can do things together with it. But this is exactly what you have explicitly ruled out in your question, and I don't understand why.